# SQL SELECT IN Array NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have an array with results = ['5', '2', '11', '12', '4'];
Now I want to make get count SQL SELECTION based on such array, that is make the SELECT IN Array SQL command. I want to return number of of rows that are there in this array from each element, I tried

[The SQL Command I tried so far is as in the image provided and my table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEYPL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you've got is exactly what I would expect from a `COUNT` statement. I think you forgot to add a `GROUP BY company_two`.

**EDIT**

To handle the case of companies not having any entry, you can do:

```
SELECT s.company_two_id, COUNT(s.id)
FROM supplies_table s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN companies_table c ON s.company_two_id = c.company_id
WHERE company_two_id IN (...)
GROUP BY s.company_two_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me try grouping. I also have noticed that count return nulls when there are no affected rows affected by such array element. Let me try the grouping

Comment: Thanks with group by GROUP BY company_two_id comes welll except that when it is zero it return null. Please help how can I write something like CASE WHEN count(id) = null count(id) = 0. Is this correct?

Comment: Something like: var q = 'SELECT count(id) CASE WHEN count(id) = NULL THEN count(id) = 0 END FROM supplies WHERE company_two_id IN ('+results.join(',')+')';

Comment: That's because there are no row for those companyIds. If you have another table with the list of company, you can try to do a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, so that the count apply on them

Comment: :) the join is doing it! thanks a lot! I am just editing it to work exactly as I want but it already working. Thanks a lot.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
select COALESCE(count(a), 0) from table1 where b in (something) group by b
```

Comment: Yes I just tried it but yet it doesn't give what I need. Thanks anyway a lot!

Comment: But I am trying out to actually do it the other way around like as in saying COUNT(COALESCE(a, 0)) and see from there but I suppose it should work